# As an EU citizen, what will UK authorities do if I overstay my 6-month visitor visa by a few days?

Tags: uk, leave-to-enter

Will they send me a letter requiring me to leave the country within 30 days? Or will this only affect future visa applications?

Comment: Do you actually have a visa or just a **leave to enter** for the standard six months?

Comment: @Robert007 EU citizens can normally enter the UK *visa-free* as a visitor, ie they are given **leave to enter** at the border. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/in-the-uk-what-is-the-difference-between-leave-to-enter-and-a-visa

Comment: How would they know where to send the letter?  Why would they tell you to leave within 30 days instead of immediately when your presence in the UK is unauthorized?

Comment: The consequences would be similar to what would happen to a UK citizen who overstayed their 90 days in the EU, I’d imagine

Comment: Judging by your previous question, you've already overstayed by almost a month.

Comment: A few weeks is definitely more serious than a few days.

Comment: If this really is the UK, 'they' will do nothing whatever unless you contact them… and if they did, 'a few days' is the grace you'd get from the time the Royal Mail would take to deliver their letter telling to scoot… and in any case, how would they know where to send their letter?

No… if it's the UK, just be very sure not to seek advice from any authority except your own country's embassy

Answer (score 18):

> Will they send me a letter requiring me to leave the country within 30 days?

The UK cannot know for sure whether or not you've left the country as you could've traveled to Ireland overland without this being recorded anywhere. So they won't be sending out letters, unless you happen to get caught in a random document check, which is quite rare.

> Or will this only affect future visa applications?

It will affect both visa applications and future attempts to enter the UK. It can also jeopardize your future travel to countries like Canada, Australia, US, New Zealand, etc, which ask about prior refusals when applying for electronic authorization to travel there.

---

My general advice is... **do not overstay**. I understand this might seem like a reasonable course of action right now, but this is a good way to mess up your future travels. Leave before the 6 months period and don't violate immigration laws during your stay. If you're worried about re-entering the UK if you leave right now and immediately try to come back, you can choose to travel to the UK via Ireland which all but guarantees you entry into the country. See [my answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/178420/9009) on a related question for details.

Comment: See the OP’s previous question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178404/can-i-stay-in-the-uk-for-six-more-months-if-i-stay-for-a-few-days-in-another-cou

Comment: The "related question" is from the same OP

Answer (score 5):

The general (unofficial) rule is that you should only return to the UK after spending the same amount of time outside of the UK as the time spent on your previous visit (which may be less than the granted **leave to enter**).

> [Immigration Rules - Immigration Rules Appendix V: Visitor - Guidance - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor)
> **Genuine visitor requirement**
> V 4.2 The applicant must satisfy the decision maker that they are a genuine visitor, which means the applicant:
> ...
> (b) will not live in the UK **for extended periods through frequent or successive visits**, or make the UK their main home; and
> ...
> (e) ...
> ...

An existing **leave to enter** is not effected by a stay in the Republic of Ireland. (CTA rules: *Exemptions from deemed leave on the basis of specific status*).

It is up to the discretion of the Immigration Officer to grant a **leave to enter**.

Even if you do not overstay by a few days, any return before 6 months may be denied since it would look as if you are trying to stay for a prelonged period after just spending 6 months in the UK.

Returning after 7-8 months, the Immigration Officer may see the overstay of a few days but may choose to ignore it if they have the impression you are not trying to stay for a prelonged period.

The situation would change if you were found in the UK while overstaying.
That would have a serious effect on any future reentry.

Comment: *The general (unofficial) rule is that you should only return to the UK after spending the same amount of time outside of the UK as the time spent on your previous visit* — uh-uh?  So if I spend two weeks in Belfast I can't make a day trip to the Republic, because I'd need to spend two weeks in the Republic before I can return to the UK?!

Comment: @gerrit For entering the UK from the Republic of Ireland (Common Travel Area) there are special rules.

Comment: I think gerrit's point is that the rule is surely more complicated? I.e. a 1-week trip followed by 1 day in France, followed by another week in the UK is surely OK. I'd say following something like "not more than 6 months in any 12 months period" should be a better rule of thumb.

Comment: @gerrit Making a day trip to the Republic after spending two weeks in Belfast is what a genuine tourist might do. Spending 6 months in the UK with a day trip to the Republic at the end would be a very different scenario. As I’m sure you know, the UK doesn’t have a strict ‘x days out of y days’ policy so the accepted norm is as described in the answer. Used with some commonsense

Comment: The CTA (Common Travel Area) rule when reentering the UK from the Republic of Ireland is an automatic **deemed leave** of 2 months. When first entering the CTA in Ireland and then entering the UK **deemed leave** of 6 months for the UK.

Comment: The 2 months only applies for those who previous had a **deemed leave** of 6 months. An existing **leave to enter** is not effected by a stay in the Republic of Ireland. (CTA rules: *Exemptions from deemed leave on the basis of specific status*)

Comment: @JonathanReez Unfortunatly the Immigration Rules are not written that way. A Standard Visitor can also, depending on the conditions, be granted up to 12 or 18 months.  [Immigration Rules - Immigration Rules Appendix V: Visitor - Guidance - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor): *V 17.3. Permission to stay will be granted for the following periods*

Comment: Sure but if we're suggesting unofficial rules of thumb, "6 months in any 12 months period" seems closer to the logic inside the immigration officers heads than "spending the same amount of time outside of the UK as the time spent on your previous visit". Otherwise two visits for 1 week with 1 day in between would supposedly not be recommended.

Comment: @JonathanReez Important is that the Immigration Officer thinks that the visit, accourding to the rules, is legitimate. The amount of time is secondary. A 2 day stay in Paris in between will cause no problem.

Comment: "The general (unofficial) rule is that you should only return to the UK after spending the same amount of time outside of the UK as the time spent on your previous visit" sorry but this is wrong, that barely factors at all in the decision at the border. 
The decisions are based on likelihood of not being a genuine visitor, so the purpose of the visit, the presence of a return ticket and evidence of work/life commitments outside the country are the main factors.

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 In the context of avoiding giving the impression of **prolonged stay** (one factor of many that Immigration Official will take into consideration) is an important factor in the determination if the person is a genuine visitor. (Immigration Rules V 4.2 (b) will not live in the UK **for extended periods through frequent or successive visits**, or make the UK their main home; and). So your claim that it 'that barely factors' is not justified considering that it is listed as the 2nd of 5 major requirements.

Comment: If you overstayed, then leave for two days and try to return, there is a chance that someone sees you overstayed and will overstay for longer, and doesn't let you enter. If you leave for a long time, they may say that you had a visit where you overstayed but not enough to take any serious action, and now you are on a second visit so they let you in .

Comment: @Mark Johnson I am aware, what I am saying is that the amount of time thumb rule does not matter. A classic example is someone who, after a long stay as a visitor, comes back for a holiday a few months later. If they can prove it is a genuine holiday (return tickets, hotel booking) etc, then the officer lets them pass.
The "prolonged stay" is not a mere thumb rule of counting days, it is mainly based on other criteria and on the consideration of the *new* trip. I'd be very cautious in making up numerical criteria, if they wanted a numerical rule they'd have put it in the rules.